# Python naming guidelines for putting numbers in variable names

Tags: python, naming-conventions, naming

I've been doing Leetcode problems in Python and I sometimes use numbers in my variable names for convenience, for example, `acc1` or `temp2`. I use these for algorithms that require keeping track of more than one index like [The Two Pointer Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/) and I was wondering if this is a big no-no in Python naming conventions so I don't make a habit of it early on. The [PEP 8 style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) recommends "lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary" and it sounds like it's implicitly forbidding numbers but I'm not 100% sure and wanted to know what others thought.

Comment: What case do you need variable with ID? Have you considered List Data Structure in Python?

Answer (score 1):

In most of the languages, the regex for variables is something like `/[a-zA-z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/` (but in python you can even use cyrillic letters in variables). For the tokenization reasons, a variable cannot start with a number.

**Style**. It's better to make easily distinguishable names for variables. In any language. Because you won't accidentally misuse a variable. It is harder to write `first_acc` instead of `second_acc` than `acc1` instead of `acc2`. So in my opinion, in the production code  use meaningful names without trying to use as little symbols as possible.

Comment: I agree in the case of typo of variable name. At the same time, isn't group of accX better than first, second, third...in reading the code and search variable?

Comment: @CloudCho yes, valid point. Maybe my example is not the best, probably better example would be to use `listOfCats` rather than `cats` (for `Cat[]` array) if there is a `cat` variable nearby.

Answer (score 1):

Python (and also other languages, such as C) allow numbers as part of a variable name, but not as the first character in a variable name. To me, that already shows that there is no absolute rule against numbers in variable names generally. Yes, I know, good style is not the same thing as what technically works with the interpreter or compiler, but it is an indication that numbers should not be considered as per se prohibited. The paramount rule is that variable names should be meaningful in the sense of making it clear to the reader what the variable is for and what kind of information it holds. There are many cases where including numbers in a variable name is in line with this principle. If your use case is one of these cases, go for it. Of course, things like `var1` are bad style, but that's because of the non-descriptive text `var`, not because of the 1. In many cases, you may also be better off with an indexable data structure such as a set (`temperature[0]`, `temperature[1]` etc.) instead of numbers as part of a variable name (`temperature1` etc.). But I think that still leaves the possibility of legitimate use cases for numbers in variable names.